# Why does the program jump to new section even though zero flag is not 0?

Tags: assembly

In the code below, I jump to the next section even if the ZF is not set because EAX is not 0.

```
Label:

mov eax, 0x02
dec eax
jz Test ; jump only if ZF = 1
```

`Test`:

```
mov ebx, 0x11
jmp Label
```

I have tested this code in GDB and, even though the ZF is not set, the program will jump to Test.

Why?  I am obviously not understanding something about conditional jumps.

Comment: If your `Test:` label is immediately after `jz Test`, this is expected...

Comment: You didn't jump, you just advanced to the next instruction. That's called a fall-through.

Comment: OK I get it. When I add a new section after Label: then if ZF =1 it will advance to Test and miss out the new section; if ZF = 0 (as in the example above) then the new section will be invoked.